# Filtering a Backbone.js collection by index

Tags: collections, filter, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have Backbone.js collection that holds (for example) 30 items.

I want to pass to my template filtered collection consist of every 3rd item in the original collection.

Does anyone know how it can be done elegantly? CoffeeScript code is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming here that `originalCollection` is your existing collection

```
var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection();

for (var i = 0, l = originalCollection.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) { newCollection.add(originalCollection.models[i]); }
}
```

This code works by looping through each existing model, and only adding the model the new collection if it's index is a multiple of 3.

You could make this a little nicer, by using the underscore `each` method exposed by Underscore.js in Backbone Collections:

```
var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection();

originalCollection.each(function (model, index) {
  if (index % 3 === 0) { newCollection.add(model); }
});
```

Converting the above to CoffeeScript results in:

```
newCollection = new Backbone.Collection()
originalCollection.each (model, index) ->
  newCollection.add model  if index % 3 is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Backbone collection have some useful [Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) mixed-in. You can use [`filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) to get an array of models that you can pass to the template:

```
filteredModels = collection.filter (model, i) -> i % 3 == 0
```

Alternatively, you can use an array comprehension; though I think this is less readable...

```
filteredModels = (model for model, i in collection.models when i % 3 == 0)
```

If you really *need* a Backbone.Collection in your template, you can create a new one with those filtered models:

```
filteredCollection = new Backbone.Collection filteredModels
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/epidemian/Lw6fR/2/) is a working jsfiddle example.